# Logit regression : glmer vs bife

Tags: r, logistic-regression, lme4

I am working on a panel dataset and trying to run a logit regression with fixed effects.

I found that glmer models from the lme4 package and the bife package are suited for this kind of work.

However when I run a regression with each model I do not have the same results (estimates, standard errors, etc.)

Here is the code and results for the glmer model with an intercept:

```
glmer_1 <- glmer(CVC_dummy~at_log + (1|year), data=own, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(glmer_1)

             Estimate  Std. Error  zvalue  Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -6.43327    0.09635   -66.77   <2e-16 ***
at_log       0.46335    0.01101    42.09   <2e-16 ***
```

Without an intercept:

```
glmer_2 <- glmer(CVC_dummy~at_log + (1|year)-1, data=own, family=binomial(link="logit"))
summary(glmer_2)

        Estimate  Std.Error  z value  Pr(>|z|)    
at_log  0.46554    0.01099   42.36   <2e-16 ***
```

And with the bife package:

```
bife_1 <- bife(CVC_dummy~at_log | year, data=own, model="logit")
summary(bife_1)

        Estimate  Std. error  t-value  Pr(> t)    
at_log   0.4679    0.0110      42.54   <2e-16 ***
```

Why are estimated coefficients of at_log different between the two packages?

Which package should I use ?

Comment: The result of the package depends on the implemented algorithm for solving the mixed effect model (Panel data with both random and fixed effects). As far as i can tell the bife package uses a method called [pseudo-demeaning](https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/145837/1/VfS_2016_pid_6909.pdf), while the lme4 uses numerical integration to solve the conditional density via laplace approximation (and similar methods). There is no guarantee these will yield (or possibly even similar) results in the two cases. To know which will be better, is a research topic, not a programming topic.

Answer (score 0):

There is quite a confusion about the terms fixed effects and random effects. From your first sentence, I guess that you intend to calculate a fixed-effects model.

However, while `bife` calculates fixed-effects models, `glmer` calculates random-effects models/mixed-effects models.

Both often get confused because random-effects models differ between fixed effects (your usual coefficients, the independent variables you are interested in) and random effects (the variances/std. dev. of your random intercepts and/or random slopes).

On the other hand, fixed-effects models are called that way because they cancel out individual differences by including a dummy variable (-1) for each group, hence by including a fixed effect for each group.

However, not all fixed-effects models work by including indicator-variables: Bife works with pseudo demeaning - yet, the results are the same and it is still called a fixed-effects model.